# how to plot variation of variable of 10 sample in a dataframe.?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the value of 21 variable and their variation in 10 samples. now I want to plot all the variables to see their variation in all the samples.
i want a plot like this.
[image]

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It goes something like this:

- In a pandas DataFrame, you can assume each column as one variable. Hence by 21 variables, I'll assume you'll have 21 columns in your dataframe.
- In a pandas DataFrame, each row can be considered as a subsample. So I'll assume here that you have 10 rows in your dataframe - with randomly populated values ranging from -1 to 1.

You now want to plot a HeatMap of these values as shown above:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(numpy.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 21))))
sns.heatmap(df)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: one more thing I have another dataset in which there are 33 variables when I plot heatmap I am getting variables 1, 3,5,7 like this. I don't know why this happens?